# Cannot read property '0' of undefined for object of objects

Tags: javascript, object, logging

I have an object of objects containing arrays. I'd like to loop through them. For the `subjects` object within `vocab`, parseHoveredText()'s `log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0]);` works fine.

Output: `log subjects, You`

But for the other objects, such as `nouns`, `verbs`, etc... , `log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0]);` gives:

Output: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I don't see how that is possible. If I put `'má'    : ['Hemp',              path+n+'Ma2_Hemp.mp3'],` within the `subjects` object, it works fine... so I think there is something wrong with the loop.

So if I change the `log` to `log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()]);`:

Output:

```
log: subjects, undefined 
log: nouns, Mother,recordings/nouns/Ma1_Mother.mp3 
log: verbs, undefined 
log: measure, undefined 
log: adjectives, undefined 
log: adverbs, undefined 
log: prepositions, undefined 
log: particles, undefined
log: suffix, undefined
```

So it's finding the keys from the other objects, as you can see it returned `Mother` from `Nouns`.

Code:

```
var path = 'recordings/';
var sbj = 'subjects/';
var n = 'nouns/';

var vocab = 
{
    "subjects" :
    {   
        'wǒ'    : ['I/Me',              path+sbj+'Wo_I.mp3'],
        'nǐ'    : ['You',               path+sbj+'Ni_You.mp3'],
        'tā'    : ['Him/Her',           path+sbj+'Ta_him.mp3'],
        'shuí'  : ['Who',               path+sbj+'Shui_Who.mp3']
    },
    "nouns" : 
    {
        'xièxiè': ['Thanks',            path+n+'Xiexie4_Thanks.mp3'],
        'duì'   : ['Correct/at/facing', path+n+'Dui4_Facing.mp3'],
        'má'    : ['Hemp',              path+n+'Ma2_Hemp.mp3'],
    etc...

function parseHoveredText (word, audio) {
    for (obj in vocab) {
    log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0]);
        if(audio) {
            return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][1];
        }
        return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you extended `Object.prototype`?

Comment: @cookiemonster what does that do and how would I extend it?

Comment: Makes every object inherit that property. It can cause problems in various ways, like when enumerating the properties of an object. What are the arguments you've given to `parseHoveredText()`?

Comment: ...also, does every property of `vocab` have an object that contains the `word` property you're passing? If not, `vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()]` would be `undefined`, and so you'd not be able to access property `[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's something a little wrong with your logic there. What's happening is that you pass a word, I'm assuming such as 'wǒ', into your parseHoveredText() function and that function tries to reference the word in every vocab object. This will always cause an error for `noun`'s or anything that is not a `subject`, because it will try to find the word in the `subject` array first.

You should be able to fix this by changing your function to:

```
function parseHoveredText (word, audio) {
    for (obj in vocab) {
        if(vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()]) {
            log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0]);
            if(audio) {
                return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][1];
            }
            return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. I knew there was something wrong with the loop, but couldn't figure out what happened. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are looping through each element of the vocab object starting with "subjects" if it can't find the "word", it can't execute command log because the variable is not defined. in javascript if a line of code breaks, the execution will stop. therefore you won't see the log you'd see otherwise. try checking if that is defined first:

```
function parseHoveredText (word, audio) {
    for (obj in vocab) {
        if(typeof vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()] !== "undefined")
        {
    console.log("log: " + obj + ", " + vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0]);
        if(audio) {
            return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][1];
        }
        return vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0];
        }
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A83pF/